# Conversión de tipos (casting) en flex/bison

Tags: flex, bison, yacc

Estoy intentado hacer un analizador el cual convierta el tipo de dato a otro es decir un casting un entero a decimal o de otro tipo que permita la conversión de un tipo de dato a otro pero no logro entender como implantar las reglas del analizador para lograr hacer el casting hacerlo he estado investigando pero no logro entender como resolver este problema espero su ayuda para poder resolver este problema gracias

```
    %{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

extern yydebug;

void yyerror(const char *str)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", str);
}

main()
{
  yydebug = 1;
  yyparse();
}
%}

%right '='
%precedence CAST
%left '('

%token AUTO BOOL BYTE DOUBLE FLOAT INT LONG SHORT SIGNED STRING UNSIGNED VOID

%token IDENTIFIER

%start file

%debug

%%

file
  : %empty
  | statement file
  ;

statement
  : expression ';'
  ;

expression
  : expression '=' expression
  | '(' type ')' expression %prec CAST
  | '(' expression ')'
  | IDENTIFIER
  ;

type
  : VOID
  | AUTO
  | BOOL
  | BYTE
  | SHORT
  | INT
  | LONG
  | FLOAT
  | DOUBLE
  | SIGNED
  | UNSIGNED
  | STRING
  | IDENTIFIER
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que el problema está en los avisos que Bison produce:

```
cast.y: aviso: 1 conflicto reducción/reducción  [-Wconflicts-rr]
cast.y:62.5-14: aviso: la regla no es útil en el analizador debido a los conflictos [-Wother]
   62 |   | IDENTIFIER
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
```

La ambigüedad del operador "cast" en el lenguaje C es notoria, aunque la gramática simplificada en esta pregunta no es ambigua. Pero, considera `a = (x)-y;`, en donde no sabes se `x` es un tipo o un variable. Podría ser `-y` convertido en tipo `x`, o bien la diferencia entre los valores del variable `x` y el variable `y`. Ninguna gramática puede resolverlo sin saber la categoría de `x`.

La solución más frecuente es dar el analizador léxico acceso al registro de símbolos para que se pueda distinguir entre identificadores nombrando tipos e identificadores nombrando variables o funciones. (Se llama "retroalimentacion léxica", o más simple, "el hack con lexer".) Para hacerlo, es necesario que hay un registro de símbolos ("symbol table") y que el analizador sintáctico sea capaz de actualizar el registro de símbolos cuando un nuevo alias de tipo está definido por un `typedef`. (Y si quieres hacerlo con precisión, tienes que tomar en cuenta que `typedef` puede crear un alias de tipo localmente.)

Si no tienes la intención de implementar `typedef`, podrías simplemente descartar `IDENTIFIER` de la definición de `type`.